# How to reduce dynamic loading moudle time in python?

Tags: python, python-import

I implemented a service with pythton, dynamically loaded the module and executed the corresponding function, and found that the first import of the module was time-consuming, can this import time be optimized?

`__import__`

Comment: Execute less code in the module.

Comment: I don't think that you can reduce this time best you can do is to keep trace of the loaded modules in a dict and use the already loaded module from the dict instead of loading it a second time. Another possible workarround would be to compile your code statically by including all possible modules in the binary but it depends of how your code work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.